# how to solve proxy using maven (IN Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, maven

when I want to create a new maven webApp project using Eclipse i get this

```
Error :
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
```

here is a part of my setting.xml :

```
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>myUsername</username>
      <password>myPasseword</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Thank you 
Here is my configuration :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Beware at the Maven version you use in Eclipse. You can check in `Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations`. 

You must check which file Maven is using for the Global and User settings in Eclipse. This can be found in `Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings`. Point at the right settings.xml and you should be good to go if your proxy configuration is correctly set.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer, but i stil have the same error (look up at pictures )

Comment: Are you sure Maven is working in a command line tool like `cmd` ? . Just saying but I find weird your proxy port. Usually it is 8080.

Please try to launch a Maven command in the cmd. (be sure to have Maven binaries added to the PATH before trying the command)

Comment: yeah, PATH already done and i tried command  mvn -version and it woks good.

Comment: I meant "Use a maven command which would be using your proxy settings like `mvn clean install`" and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 2):

@MadJlzz , using Goals in commande line works perfectly
But, in eclipse still the problem
[image]

Comment: Okay thanks. Did you set any proxy in Eclipse's general configuration ? I had a similar issue when setting both Eclipse and Maven's proxy. 

If so, please set the Eclipse's proxy in `Native Mode` and test again in Eclipse.